# Why in ckpt folder the weight files are not generated while training the custom object detection model

Tags: object-detection, yolo

I've created my own dataset in image format then while writing command given below then my model was started training and all the steps were shown but the weight files were not generated. I don't know why? if anyone can help with it..

command that I've tried:

```
python flow --model cfg/tiny-yolo-voc-1c.cfg --load bin/tiny-yolo-voc.weights --train --annotation new_model/annotations --dataset new_model/images --epoch 300
```

I expect the weight files to be generated after some training steps

Comment: is it not generated when you use `--load` only? Are you training by loading checkpoint or from beginning?

Comment: From beginning while training for my own dataset it doesn't generate any weight files....and if weight files are not generated then how I can apply the new trained model on custom object s? That's the problem...I searched and found it may generate after 100/ 150 steps of training but in my case even after that much steps it is not generated..!

Comment: what's the command that you use when you train at first time without loading the checkpoint weight?

Comment: Same command as I mentioned above

Comment: even if you add `--savepb` still not working?

Comment: Yes I've tried using --savepb still it's not working